# Qt GUI Design - Is there an invisible character suitable for label text?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

Okay I'm working on a GUI with Qt Designer for c++, and I have a bunch of labels setup to display some content from a file once it is loaded.

On the labels that are used to display loaded content, I currently have them set to "*set later*", and in the initial GUI configuration, I call `ui->label_id.setText("");` on each of the labels before they can be seen.  I really just want them to have some text so I can visually see them in the designer, yet not have any when the program is running before content is loaded.

So my question is: **Is this the best way to handle this? Or is there a character I can set the text to in designer that won't appear at runtime?**

With more and more labels as my gui expands, I don't want to bog down the loading time of the program setting the text to "" for every one, so that's why I'm here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution could be to set a color to that labels with a transparent color (0 alpha value).
This can be handled via a style sheet in the widget constructor:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
   QMainWindow(parent),
   ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
   ui->setupUi(this);

   setStyleSheet("QLabel { color: qrgba(255, 255, 255, 0); }");
}
```

If you want to selectively apply a stylesheet to a label, you could use all kinds of [Qt Style Sheet Selector Types](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types). 
You could use the ID Selector for example. If you've set in QtDesigner the `objectName` attribute of a label to `label_1`, you hide this label selectively by setting this style sheet:

```
setStyleSheet("#label_1 { color: qrgba(255, 255, 255, 0); }");
```

A more advanced solution would be a method that returns the style sheet for the object names:

```
QString MainWindow::styleSheetForHiddenLabels(const QStringList &labelObjectNames)
{
   QString styleSheet;

   foreach (QString labelName, labelObjectNames) {
      QString style("#");
      style.append(labelName);
      style.append(" { color: qrgba(255, 255, 255, 0); }");
      styleSheet.append(style);
   }

   return styleSheet;
}
```

This method could be used this way:

```
QStringList labelNames;
labelNames << "label1" << "label2" << "label3";

QString stylesheet = styleSheetForHiddenLabels(labelNames);
setStyleSheet(stylesheet);
```

Comment: Hey this works nicely.  I don't know much about stylesheets though, is there a way to apply this selectively to certain labels, maybe with some kind of filtering?

Comment: Very nice! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the stylesheet answer.

```
QList<QLabel*> widgets = this->findChildren<QLabel*>();

for (QLabel *label : widgets) {
    label->setText("");
}
```

place this in your MainWindow class constructor. It will get a list of all QLabels from your window, you can then cycle through them and set the text to "".

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object inspector. In Object inspector you'll se a list of your labels, and when you click on some of your labels you'll see border around your widget. That way you can see your labels without putting any text in it.